# Async Method not Returning a String

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I am trying to get some weather data from Open Weather Maps and l use HTTPClient and API  ASP.NET in C#.
My code keeps returning:

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]

I've made my methods `async` and `await` but I still get the above returned. I thought making it `await` would return the value.

I am just trying to get the string from Open Weather Maps, I'll worry about parsing it to JSON once I have this working. Here is my code, "MY_APPID" is replaced with my API key, I just removed it here.

My main:

```
private async Task<string> GetLocationJson()
    {
        const string APPID = "(MY_APPID)";
        const string LOCATIONID = "2172797";
        string jsonAsString = ""; 
        string callStringJson = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=" + LOCATIONID + "&appid=" + APPID;

        ApiCalls weatherApi = new ApiCalls(callStringJson);
        jsonAsString = await weatherApi.GetLocationJson();
        return jsonAsString;
    }

    //ShowLocationJson is called on button click
    protected void ShowLocationJson(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        litOutput.Text = GetLocationJson().ToString();
    }
```

And my ApiCalls Class is:

```
public class ApiCalls
{

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Uri url;
    
    public ApiCalls(string link)
    {
        url = new Uri("https://" + link);            
    }

    public async Task<string> GetLocationJson()
    {
        string content = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        return content;
    }
}
```

`url` variable is being passed the correct values so I know it's ok up to there.

Im using ASP.NET Framework 4.5 as well

Comment: You should _await_ the call to _GetLocationJson()_ and remove the ToString. Also the  _ShowLocationJson_ should be async

Comment: You need to await *all* your async calls, including calls to GetLocationJson. And anywhere that you call that method need to be marked as async. Event handlers can be marked as async and return void, one of the few places that's allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve and mason have already noticed you have to await all methods returning Task. You need to change your ShowLocationMethod to:

```
protected async void ShowLocationJson(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    litOutput.Text = await GetLocationJson();
}
```

You receive `System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[System.String]` because you call method ToString() of Task object. The default implementation of the [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netcore-3.1) method returns the fully qualified name of the type of the object: `Task<String>`

Comment: Hi, I am using ASP.NET Framework 4.5. I have made the changes you mentioned and when i run it i get a comile error becuase the event handler linked to OnClick for my button is no longer recognised (ShowLocationJson)

Comment: @mason yeah then I end up back where I started with the text displayed in the Literal as _System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[System.String]_  when I use `ToString()`. When I dont include `ToString()` I get error _cannot implicitly convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> to string_. I think maybe im trying to do something I shouldnt and I should just parse the response into json and display that how I want on Page Load?

Comment: @zolty13 and @mason i added `<%@ Page Async="true"` to my page and made the changes you suggested and it now works. Apologies for not being clearer in my questioning. Thank you for your help